# Is it possible to change the length of the underline?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's what I have, I want my underline to be shorter in length and centered.

```
 TextButton(
            child: Text ('Beverages', style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Milkshake', fontSize: 60,
                shadows: [Shadow(color: Colors.white, offset: Offset(0, -20),),],
                color: Colors.transparent,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                decorationColor: Colors.white, decorationThickness: 0.3),),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom (
              backgroundColor: Color (0xFF2D4067),),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FourthRoute(),),);
            }
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and for this you should use the `Divider` widget, and set the `indent` to your desired value

[More Information on the Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html)